# Externalizing Spring Kafka configuration with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have this kafka config class

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {
    @Value("${KAFKA_SERVERS}")
    private String kafkaServers;


    @Bean
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(this.consumerFactory());
        factory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(this.consumerConfigs());
    }

    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "foo-group-id");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 0);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 33554432);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaProperties.Listener listener() {
        return new KafkaProperties.Listener();
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Map<String, Object>> kafkaTemplateHistory() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(this.producerConfigs()));
    }
}
```

And I want to use spring boot auto configuration so to get ride of the config class above, so I set almost all the properties in `appliction.yml`

but for these two properties :

```
ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG
ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG
```

`spring.kafka.consumer` doesn't propose me anything

1. So how can I set them in `appliction.yml` ?
2. Also how to externalize this setting line `factory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());` ?

Answer (score 6):

you can set those properties by using [spring.kafka.producer.properties.*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#spring.kafka.producer.properties)

> Additional producer-specific properties used to configure the client.

```
spring:
   kafka:
     producer:
       properties:
         linger.ms: 10
```

For consumer additional properties you can use [spring.kafka.consumer.properties.*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#spring.kafka.consumer.properties) with trusted package so you don't need the converter

```
spring:
   kafka:
     consumer:
       properties:
         sesssion.timeout.ms: 60000
```

And for consumer desrializer you can use this [spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer)

> Deserializer class for values.

```
 spring:
   kafka:
    consumer:
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      properties:
        spring:
          json:
            trusted:
              packages: 'learn.kafka.model'
```

Comment: Correct. For more information, see the Boot documentation "Additional Kafka Properties" https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-kafka-extra-props

Comment: For question #2; simply define the converter as a `@Bean` and Spring Boot will automatically wire the converter into the container factory.

Comment: That's a good point @GaryRussell but as per my understanding converter bean is not necessary if we set thr trusted packages right? Please feel free to correct me

Comment: He doesn't need the trusted packages property, he's using a `StringDeserializer` with a `StringJsonMessageConverter`. With that configuration, we infer the type from the method signature and the conversion from JSON is done by the converter rather than the deserializer. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#messaging-message-conversion